# Convert GPlinearunit to float in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, valueerror

Is it possible that arcpy converts all inputs of the a value registered as GPlinearunit (kilometers, meters, feet, miles, etc) into units of XY coordinates system?
I need to perform calculations with it, since ArcPy GPlinearunit recognizes the parameter as a string.

I have:

```
import arcpy, math

source = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # < feeature point
w = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # <- Double
d = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # <- GPlinearunit

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(source, ["SHAPE@XY"]):
    x, y = row[0]
    arcpy.AddMessage("{}, {}".format(x, y))

rad = float(w) / 57.2957795
arcpy.AddMessage("{}".format(rad))
dX = x + float(d) * math.cos(rad)
dY = y + float(d) * math.sin(rad)
arcpy.AddMessage("{}, {}".format(dX, dY))
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\AIR-GIS\toolbox\scripts\Perfil.py", line 26, in  dX = x +
>   float(d) * math.cos(rad) ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 5
>   Kilometers Failed to execute (Perfil).

I found a solution: convert all units in meters.

```
digit = int(filter(str.isdigit, str(d)))
arcpy.AddMessage(str(digit))
letters = str(filter(str.isalpha, str(d)))
arcpy.AddMessage(str(letters))

if letters == "Meters":
    dfloat = float(digit)
elif letters == "Kilometers":
    dfloat = float(digit) * 1000
elif letters == "Unknown":
    dfloat = float(digit)
elif letters == "Feet":
    dfloat = float(digit) * 3.28084

rad = float(w) / 57.2957795
dX = x + dfloat * math.cos(rad)
dY = y + dfloat * math.sin(rad)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a code snippet so we can see what you've got and what you need to change

Comment: Sorry, I added the code.

Comment: what happens when you use `float(d)`?

Comment: The message is: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AIR-GIS\toolbox\scripts\Perfil.py", line 26, in <module>
    dX = x + float(d) * math.cos(rad)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 5 Kilometers

Failed to execute (Perfil).

Comment: Try printing `d` to see what is being pulled through from your tool dialog.  I think you will find it is a string (you are using `GetParameterAsText`) of "5 Kilometers" and not a number as string i.e. "5".

Comment: Please always include error messages within your question body.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm novice in here. Yes, the output is "5 kilometers"!, this is a string. When I use "double" I haven't problem. But, I wonder if it is possible to convert this string to float.

Comment: I cannot see what your output from those AddMessage functions are without investing time to construct a test to do so.  Can you include the output in your question so that I can figure how to minimize the time I need to volunteer on this question, please?  I think it would be worth you reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers

Comment: At some point I suspect your question will become a duplicate of this Q&A or one like it: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66888

Comment: I found a very tedious way:
I will edit my question. Because, I don't know put a code here.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing `d` to see what is being pulled through from your tool dialog.

I think you will find it is a string (because you are using `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()`) of "5 Kilometers" and not a number as string i.e. "5".

To see what I am getting at perhaps run this test from any Python IDE:

```
d = "5 Kilometers"

print type(d)

kmFloat = float(d.split(" ")[0])

print kmFloat
print type(kmFloat)
```

You should see:

```
>>> 
<type 'str'>
5.0
<type 'float'>
>>>
```

Comment: It works! But, split the string. When the input is in "meters", the output is different. Is possible that arcpy transform all inputs (kilometers, meters, feet, miles) in the units of XY coordinates system?

Comment: @MarcoUscuchagua Perhaps, I found this poorly documented when I looked just now.  If you want to [edit] your question to improve it with that test case and test output then I can re-test and adjust my answer.